# ionic2 : content in slides not scrolling

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have a couple of slides which have dynamic content that is added to them. The problem is the content inside of the slides doesn't scroll. So if I have a lot of items only some show and there is no ability to slide. How can I make it so the content in my lists slides inside of their slides?

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slides (change)="onSlideChanged($event)">
        <ion-slide >
            <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="#item of items1; #i = index">
            <h2>{{item}</h2>
            </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-slide>
         <ion-slide>
                 <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="#item of items2; #i = index">
            <h2>{{item}</h2>
            </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem,and I solve it like this:

```
    <ion-slides style="height: auto">
       <ion-slide *ngFor="#item of items">
           <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
           <p>{{item.description}}</p>
       </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to wrap your long content in a `<scroll-content>` inside of each `<ion-slide>`, for example:

```
<ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="#item of items">
      <scroll-content>
        <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
      </scroll-content>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Note, you may need to do a `text-align:left` if you want the text to not be centered, since thats the default for content in `<ion-slide>`.

Comment: I had to use `ion-scroll` instead of `scroll-content` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `style='height:auto'` as stated in [booyoungxu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176943/2334352) disables sliding after you swipe on the first slide. `style='overflow:scroll'` works best.

```
<ion-slides style="height: auto">
...
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller, put:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.slides.autoHeight = true;
}
```